# Django application installation

Tags: django

I'm still busy with my Django learning adventure. In another post I asked about how to structure a Django project and applications using buildout. In the details of doing this arose another issue, simply installing 3rd party Django applications using either easy_install or setup.py. My question is, where should you install a Django application? If looking at Django documentation, one would think to put a Django application inside the project folder. But if your Django application is an egg (a mystifying term in my opinion) and you use easy_install without option '-b' (build-directory) the application will be installed into your current python site-packages directory. Using option '-b' will put a copy of the application in your directory, but still will install it in your current site-packages directory. Then there are other options like --install-dir and prefix. Also how should installation happen when using setup.py which have similar options as buid-directory, install-dir, and prefix?

Is there a 'good practice' standard for installing 3rd party Django applications into a Django project?

Thank a lot,

Todd

Answer (score 0):

They usually aren't installed directly into the project. They're either installed into the system's `site-packages/` directory, or in the virtualenv's `site-packages/` directory, or in some other well-defined place that the sysadmin has set for this purpose.

Comment: Alright thanks,

So that's okay, to have django applications floating around in the site-packages directory. I thought a Django project should have all it's project/application code available in the same location.

Cheers,

T

Answer (score 0):

This is where virtualenv comes into its own. It basically enables a project-specific site_packages directory, where you can install all the third-party applications that relate to your project. I'd definitely recommend it.

Comment: Thank Daniel,

Yes I'm using virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper actually. So far the best practice is to go ahead and easy_install into the site-packages directory of an enclosed python.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps : 
change the path according to your local setup

1. C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages>python pip install django
2. Create Project
   Go to folder where you want to create a project 
   E:\djangoProject>C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py startproject myproject

   > python manage.py help is used to list all the commands 
   >   Manage.py  This file is kind of your project local django-admin for interacting with your project via command line (start the development server, sync db...)
3. Run Server 
   E:\djangoProject\myproject>python manage.py runserver
4. Create App
   E:\djangoProject\myproject>python manage.py startapp myapp
5. Go to myproject  settings.py and register your app “myapp” created under INSTALLED_APPS
6. Migrate DB  E:\djangoProject\myproject>python manage.py migrate
   Migrate will create necessary tables or collections depending on your db type, necessary for the admin interface to run